# how can i print vim register value in command line mode?

Tags: vim, zsh, neovim

Hey i want to print `javap java.lang.Object` in vim terminal but not for only 'Object' class but any class that i yanked in particular register.

let say i yanked word `Integer` with `"kyaw` in vim so i want to print output of `javap java.lang.Integer`.

For that i tried this command but that's not working.

```
:term javap "java.lang.${echo @k}"
```

but in vim terminal it's giving me error like

```
zsh:1: bad substitution
```

i think that `echo @k` is not working in `"` so what i do to expand there particular keyword like `Object` or `Integer`.

Comment: I haven't understood what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's easier to build the command as a string then run it with `:execute`:

```
:execute 'term javap \"java.lang.'..@k..'\"'
```

or

```
:execute printf('term javap \"java.lang.%s\"', @k)
```

Note that the `"` are escaped with a backslash, and `..` is the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 2):

In the command-line, inserting the content of a register is done with `:help c_ctrl-r`. In your case:

```
:term javap java.lang.<C-r>k<CR>
```

Which could easily be turned into a simplistic mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :term javap java.lang.<C-r>k<CR>
```

And improved by using the word under the cursor directly instead of yanking something in a separate step:

```
nnoremap <key> :term javap java.lang.<C-r><C-w><CR>
```